# How do references work in ASP.NET WebForms websites (not web applications)?

Tags: asp.net, web

I have taken over an old ASP.NET *website* (as opposed to a *web application*) and I am having problems getting it to build in our CI environment due to an unresolved reference to the [Ajax Control Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/).

I see the same error on my local development machine, and can fix it by manually adding a reference to AjaxControlToolkit.dll (the project's NuGet packages.config file references the Ajax Control Toolkit).

However, ASP.NET websites do not have a .csproj file (unlike web applications), so making this change doesn't seems to update any file in the source code tree.

When I build the website in Visual Studio I can see it copying a large number of other dlls into the website's `Bin` folder. All apart from `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`...

So my question is basic: How do ASP.NET WebForm websites manage their references?

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net website has a folder Bin. In this folder all references are placed you just need to copy and paste dll files into Bin folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however when I build the website in Visual Studio it copies a large number of other dlls into the `Bin` folder, but not `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`. I've updated my question to state this.

Comment: You will have to manually copy and paste this dll into Bin folder and if you are not using AjaxControlToolKit then remove it from your web.config

Comment: But, how does the build know to copy the other dlls into the Bin folder, but not this one?

Comment: Build doesn't copy files it only builds the dlls present in the bin folder and if a missing dll is referenced somewhere it throws error.

Comment: I don't think that's correct - on my machine I can see that when I perform a build, dlls get copied to the `Bin` folder.

Comment: Ok you can make sure this.Take backup of all files in bin and delete all of them and then rebuild and check if files are copied into bin or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59713/discussion-between-richard-everett-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the system is that ASP.Net handles references in several different ways:

**Referenced projects** are stored in the "solution" file typically in the main directory, if you edit the file in notepad you should see references in the following format:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ActiveDirectoryHelper", "..\..\DataAccess\ActiveDirectoryHelper\ActiveDirectoryHelper.csproj", "{D1DDF7A2-6F69-4400-92A7-FD7F4CD87FE8}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "XXX.Library", "..\..\DataAccess\XXXLibrary\XXX.Library.csproj", "{F0A396FA-4588-41E8-B072-7121501689FA}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Common", "..\..\DataAccess\Common\Common.csproj", "{F80C48D8-F6AD-43A2-8AB0-7E4A8461D372}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DataAccess", "..\..\DataAccess\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj", "{F9AEC8CE-6E04-4848-8168-1436EBA4E734}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DataAccess.Tests", "..\..\DataAccess\DataAccessTests\DataAccess.Tests.csproj", "{472C68E1-66AA-486D-9B76-BC72254BB0F9}"
```

**Third party "DLL's"**, these are stored by including a "refresh" file in the "Bin" directory. If your using source control of any type don't forget to check these files in:

[image]

*(TFS Example)*

[image]

If you open the "refresh" file you will see something like the following:

```
Library\AjaxControlToolkit.dll
```

**NuGet** I think is a bit more compiled see the [details listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045289/2912011) for a strategy on how to approach this.

**Standard and third party library's**, are also mentioned in the "web.config" file, I assume this is how they are referenced:

```
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="CustomMarshalers, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.VisualC, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

None of this I've ever seen official documentation on, all of it I've derived from my struggles with TFS or Visual Studio over the years, I wish there was something official written up on this that people could reference. Microsoft's official documentation has a tendency to [glaze over](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178728.aspx) important details such as these, and when stuff breaks your left playing detective with undocumented low level implementation details...