# Clarifying `.dll.refresh` files, source control, and build of an asp.net web site project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dependencies

I'm working in an ASP.NET Web Site project *([as opposed to an Web Application project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/398037/3258851), meaning it doesn't have a `.csproj` file)*.

The solution is structured like this:

```
-Solution
   |-dlls
   |   |-AjaxControlToolkit.dll
   |-packages
   |   |-Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1
   |   |   |-(...)
   |   |-RestSharp.106.6.7
   |       |-(...)
   |-WebSiteProject
   |   |-Bin
   |   |   |-(.refresh files listed below)
   |   |-packages.config
   |   |-(other website files)
```

After a fresh checkout from source control, in the `Bin` folder I have these:

- *AjaxControlToolkit.dll.refresh*:

  ```
  ..\dlls\AjaxControlToolkit.dll
  ```
- *Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll.refresh*:

  ```
  ..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll
  ```
- *RestSharp.dll.refresh*:

  ```
  ..\packages\RestSharp.106.6.9\lib\net452\RestSharp.dll
  ```
- *roslyn/csc.exe.refresh*:

  ```
  ..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\tools\roslynlatest\csc.exe
  ```

  ...and other files in the `roslyn` folder ending in `.dll.refresh`, all similar to `csc.exe.refresh` above.

Upon building the web site, these files appear in the `Bin` folder:

- ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll
- restsharp.dll
- restsharp.dll.xml

*But*, `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll` does not, and neither do any of the binary files in `roslyn/`. Thus, the site cannot validate/run.

**I have three questions, all closely related:**

1. Is it correct to check-in to source control (TFS) only the files ending in `.refresh` and assume the binaries will be copied locally by the build process?
2. How are `ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll` and `restsharp.dll` copied correctly (from `Solution/dlls` and `Solution/packages/RestSharp.105.2.3`, respectively), even though the relative paths are wrong?
3. Why is the same magic not working for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll` and for all binaries in the `roslyn` directory?

Note: because this is a web site project, sure there are no pre- or post-build events.

Thanks.

P.S. the contents of `WebSiteProject/packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.6.9" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found.

> 1. Is it correct to check-in to source control (TFS) only the
>      files ending in .refresh and assume the binaries will be copied
>      locally by the build process?

It is, not necessarily by the "build process" though (in quotes because there isn't actually a *build* per se). I found that simply clicking another project in the solution, then clicking the web site project again, will trigger the copy. Or also, clicking the Refresh button in the Solution Explorer's top bar (when the web site project has focus).

But there is a caveat: this only works for files directly in the `Bin` folder (not for those in `Bin/roslyn` for example), no matter if the paths are correct (I even tried absolute paths, which works in `Bin`, but not under `Bin/subdir`.

> 2. How are `ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll` and `restsharp.dll` copied correctly (from `Solution/dlls` and
>      `Solution/packages/RestSharp.105.2.3`, respectively), even though the
>      relative paths are wrong?

After some testing I concluded that the paths are relative from the project directory (what would be `$(ProjectPath)` in a web application project).

> 3. Why is the same magic not working for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll` and for all
>      binaries in the `roslyn` directory?

It *was* in fact working for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll.refresh`. Regarding `roslyn/*`, see the caveat in question 1.