# Visual Studio 2022 - could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

So I'm back from a nice Christmas break - and completely stymied.  When I try to build my Visual Studio 2022 solution I get this message:

```
Build (web): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also get this in VS 2019 too.  My website is ASP.NET webforms - I've got two other MVC websites which build and run perfectly.  Here is the relevant section of my web.config file:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Printing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
```

I've just spent 3 hours reading through blogs like this StackOverflow one:

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework'(VS 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330915/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-build-frameworkvs-2017)

I've tried restarting Visual Studio, and even turning my computer off and on again.  I've commented out the assembly lines in the **web.config** file shown above.  I went into Nuget package manager and added **Microsoft.Build.Framework** to see if this would help (it didn't).

Here's what the project references look like:

[image]

I've had this sort of problem on numerous other occasions, and usually sorted it fairly quickly - but not this time.  I know little about building projects - I just want Visual Studio to do it all for me!

Can any kind person help please?

Comment: I assume you done a clean project? (then shut down vs) and delete everything in the bin folder. You not mentioned if this is a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site application? Regardless, try a clean, and then a re-build all. Also, check the project references page - see if any references are missing.

Comment: It's an ASP.NET website.  I'd dearly love to rewrite it in MVC, but there's just too much legacy code.  I don't have a clean project option (though I have rebuilt the solution - many times).  I've added the references diagram to the initial question above.

Comment: I deleted the contents of the bin folder, which added another error message about not being able to find a licenses file.  I restored the files and then deleted everything apart from App_Licences.dll, which solved this problem and just showed my original error message.

Answer (score 1):

So I've at least got this in a working state - here's an update for anyone else facing this nightmare (and who, like me, doesn't fully understand what building involves).

I still have the build error, but if I right-click on a .aspx file to view it in a browser this now works (before it gave a compilation error).  To reach this state I removed any references to any Microsoft.Build libraries that I had set in Nuget.  I don't know whether this helped or not!

Of course I can't debug (because this requires a build), so this is at best a temporary fix, but at least I can do some work on the website.

Someone also mentioned this page, which gives a good summary of the opacity of the build process:

[How do references work in ASP.NET WebForms websites (not web applications)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422421/how-do-references-work-in-asp-net-webforms-websites-not-web-applications)

Comment: If you think this fixes your problem, you can mark it.

Comment: I don't - 2 months on and I need to debug to solve a problem, and can't.  This is one of the most expensive problems I've come across in terms of time lost!